# How to find all activities generated by one schedule reminder?

Tags: api, scheduled-reminders, advanced-search

As the question says - **How to find all activities generated by one schedule reminder ?**

You can find all activities of type 'scheduled reminder'. This shows a few fields, but not which instance of the scheduled reminder created this activity. You can filter the search by activity 'subject' and 'details', but I don't think the instance of the scheduled reminder is in there (?).

Using the api (explorer) you can get a lot of relationships to activities, like 'medium' and 'parent', but I'm not sure what these mean. Is that information (which scheduled reminder created this activity) lost ?

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is to search by the email's subject line - but I'm assuming you have multiple scheduled reminders with the same subject line.

You can find details in the `civicrm_action_log` table.  The `action_schedule_id` is the ID of the scheduled reminder.  That said, I can't 100% recall how this handles sending the same reminder multiple times - either because repetition is enabled, or because the same membership comes up for renewal multiple times.  Hopefully neither of those apply to you, but if they do, you may need to compare that data against the activity log to see how it's represented.

Comment: Yes, same subject line - in fact, same body in some instances. From now on, I'm going to hide some secret hidden code in the html body of my reminders so I can filter on those...